# Livewire: how to disable fetch requests to the server when the model changes?

Tags: laravel-livewire

Every time a field in the model changes, a request is sent to the server with the changes in the component. This is crazy behavior.
Why is this done? Why aren't changes being processed on the client side?

Example: user model. I write an email address and when you enter each character, a request is sent to the server. The length of the email address is 24 characters - 24 requests were sent to the server.

How can I disable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Every time a field in the model changes, a request is sent to the
> server with the changes in the component. This is crazy behavior. Why
> is this done? Why aren't changes being processed on the client side?

This is by design and how Livewire works when you bind an `input` field with a `component` `property`.

> How can I disable this?

There are a few options available to you:

1. Increase the `debounce` value which by default is set to `150ms`.

```html
<input type="text" wire:model.debounce.500ms="name">
```

2. Only send a request to the server once the input elements native `change` event has been fired (user clicks away).

```html
<input type="text" wire:model.lazy="message">
```

3. Defer sending the request to the server until such a time where an action is performed to manually trigger a server request:

```html
<input type="text" wire:model.defer="query">
<button wire:click="search">Search</button>
```

Comment: why send requests to the server if they don't make sense?

Comment: @SanyaH It might not make sense for your use case, but there are use cases where real time updates do make sense. For example; a search component where as you type, data in a table is updated in real time.

Comment: the inclusion of the functionality of receiving data from the server for re-rendering is expected, but such functionality is by no means by default

Comment: @SanyaH Actually, it is the default behaviour [as per the docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#data-binding)

Comment: In release 3, this behavior has been fixed. And now everything will be as it should have been originally